# Trigger not updating records - DML not being called(?)

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I created a Trigger on Contact to update the associated Account each time a Contact is added or edited; the Trigger checks that each Contact in the Account has a valid credit card associated with it, and then ticks a checkbox if this condition is met, or unticks the box if the condition is not met.

I am new to Apex and suspect that the issue lies with how I am calling the DML - could anyone tell me where it is I am going wrong?

Thanks

```
trigger checkAccountAllCreditCardNumbersValid on Contact__c(after insert, after update, after delete){
    
       //create new Set to store our Accounts
    Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
    
    
      //add every account affected by the Trigger
      for(Contact__c : Trigger.New){
          if(c.Account__c !=null) 
              accountIdSet.add(c.Account__c);
      }
      
    System.debug('accountIdSet.size() = ' + accountIdSet.size());
    
    //create List of all Accounts found in accountIdSet
    List<Account> accToContact = [SELECT Id,
                                  (SELECT Id, NAME, Credit_card_number__c 
                                   FROM Contacts)
                                 FROM Account WHERE Id in:accountIdSet];
    
    
    System.debug('accToContact.size()' + accToContact.size());
    

    
    //loop through the affected Accounts, and set 'All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c' = true only if all Contacts have a valid credit card number saved
    
    //empty List of Accounts to update for DML statement
    
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    
     for(Account ac: accToContact){
         for(Contact c: ac){
             if(c.Credit_card_number__c != null){
                 ac.All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c = true;
                 
                 accountsToUpdate.add(ac);
             }
         }
         
         
     }
     
     
     System.debug('accountsToUpdate.size() = ' + accountsToUpdate.size());
     //dml
     update accountsToUpdate;
    
}
```

Comment: Note that the trigger is on a custom `Contact__c` object, not the standard `Contact`. Also note that the query for contacts against the `Account` records will not conside the records currently being added, updated or deleted since the trigger is called before the current DML operation makes changes to the database.

Comment: why do you call the AllValidCreditCards in the account nested loop and not not at the beginning of boolean method

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your loop:

```
for(Account ac: accToContact){
     for(Contact c: ac){
         if(c.Credit_card_number__c != null){
             ac.All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c = true;                
             accountsToUpdate.add(ac);
         }
     }       
 }
```

What you are doing is looping through all contacts for an Account and if *any* Contact has a non-null `Credit_Card_Number__c`, you set the flag on the parent account `All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c` to true - and then add the Account to the update list.

Consider an Account with three Contacts:

```
C1 - non-null Credit_Card_Number__c
C2 - null Credit_Card_Number__c
C3 - non-null Credit_Number__c
```

Clearly, the parent Account should not have `All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c` set to true, nor should you be adding the account to the update list twice.

Now how to solve this?

### Option 1

```
for(Account ac: accToContact){
     Boolean hasAllValidCreditCards = true;
     for(Contact c: ac){
         if(c.Credit_card_number__c == null){
             hasAllValidCreditCards = false; // found a Contact w/o creditcard
             break;
         }
     }
     if (hasAllValidCreditCards) { // all contactsHaveValid CC
         ac.All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c = true;                
     }
     else { // at least 1 Contact has null cc
         ac.All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c = false;
     }           
 }
```

### Option 2

Let the database do the work for you

```
.. get accountIds from trigger context

// build two maps - accounts w/ all contacts, accounts w/ contacts w/ credit cards
Map<Id,Account> accountsWithContactsByAccountId =
   new Map<Id,Account> (
      [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) 
       FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accountIdSet]);

Map<Id,Account> accountsWithContactsWithCreditCardsByAccountId =
   new Map<Id,Account> (
      [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts
                         WHERE Credit_Card_Number__c != null) 
       FROM Account WHERE Id IN: accountIdSet]);

for (Account a : accountsWithContactsByAccountId.keySet()) {
   // if lists are of diff arity, we know not all contacts have valid cc
   accountsToUpdate.add(
      new Account(
                  Id = a.Id,
                  All_Valid_Credit_Cards__c =          
                    accountsWithContactsByAccountId
                      .get(a.Id).Contacts.size() ==              
                    accountsWithContactsWithCreditCardsByAccountId
                      .get(a.Id).Contacts.size() 
        ));
}
```

**Notes**

1. As Phil W pointed out, your trigger is on custom object `Contact__c` but you are querying Accounts and standard object children `Contact`. I assume this is deliberate. If not, you'll need the subquery to consider custom relationship `Contacts__r`, not `Contacts`.